# Only view the CPU temperature from command `sensors`

Tags: command-line

Ok, so when I run the command:

```
sensors
```

I get a truck load of info:

```
atk0110-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
Vcore Voltage:     +1.16 V  (min =  +0.85 V, max =  +1.60 V)
 +3.3 Voltage:     +3.39 V  (min =  +2.97 V, max =  +3.63 V)
 +5 Voltage:       +5.17 V  (min =  +4.50 V, max =  +5.50 V)
 +12 Voltage:     +12.36 V  (min = +10.20 V, max = +13.80 V)
CPU FAN Speed:    1906 RPM  (min =  600 RPM)
CHASSIS FAN Speed:   0 RPM  (min =  600 RPM)
CPU Temperature:   +31.0°C  (high = +60.0°C, crit = +95.0°C)  
MB Temperature:    +32.0°C  (high = +45.0°C, crit = +95.0°C)
```

What would the command be if I just wanted to see this:

```
CPU Temperature:   +31.0°C  (high = +60.0°C, crit = +95.0°C)
```

or better yet, just this:

```
CPU Temperature:   +31.0°C
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can process the output of `sensors` command with `grep` and/or `cut` to format it the way you want.

To get only the line reporting the CPU temperature you can use this (including the high and critical limits):

```
sensors | grep -A 0 'CPU T'
```

The following will give you only the temperature (with the °C suffix) :

```
sensors | grep -A 0 'CPU T' | cut -c18-25
```

This will give the output as you indicated at the end of your question:

```
sensors | grep -A 0 'CPU T' | cut -c1-25
```

Comment: Thanks a million, this has helped me so much, though one thing, the output in Terminal is perfect it reads as:
>CPU Temperature: +33.0°C
But when I try to output to firefox I get:
>CPU Temperature: +33.0Â°C
Which looks untidy, any suggestions?

Comment: I have seen the same as well (especially while working with Conky). I don't know why this happens, though I am able work around it. In case of conky, I `cut` off the output only until the value (without the °C suffix) and then add this as static text. Can you detail what is the problem you are trying to solve that requires you to pipe this output to firefox ?

Comment: I'm working towards my server being able to send me a tweet on twitter when it reaches a certain temperature. Thank you for giving me a hand!

Comment: Ah! now I understand. Would it still help, if you use `sensors | grep -A 0 'CPU T' | cut -c18-22` (which is chop off the *c suffix) and format this into a tweet ? Like so: ` echo "$(sensors | grep -A 0 'CPU T' | cut -c1-22)" degree C` Play with the cut interval (`c1-22`) till you are satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

The string below should work for you. grep -A[4] gives the next 4 lines 
The watch -d refreshes the changes and -d highlights the difference from the last refresh.

watch -d 'sensors | grep 'CPU Temperature''

Answer (score 1):

Install the small `apci` package with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install acpi
```

You will need to press <kbd>Y</kbd> for confirmation for the first time.

Now to find the CPU temperature with this command:

```
acpi -t
```